# Is there a Djangonic way to get Django objects from a list defaulting to all() if the list is empty?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

For example something like `MyModel.objects.filter(some_value___in=[1,2], ignore_null_some_value=True)` would return MyModels with some_values 1 or 2, but `MyModel.objects.filter(some_value__in=[], ignore_null_some_value=True)` would return all instances of MyModel?

My best effort so far is to do a second db query earlier to make sure the list is populated, e.g.:

```
values = <list> or MyModel.objects.values_list('some_value', flat=True))
MyModel.objects.filter(some_value__in=values)
```

But this feels inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You will evaluate query twice anyway so I suggest to do just:

```
filtered_qs = MyModel.objects.filter(some_value___in=[1,2])

return filtered_qs or MyModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: I might want to include other filter conditions though, in which case I think this wouldn't work? If the `some_value` list was empty you'd end up ignoring the other conditions and returning everything

Comment: The answer was based on example you provided. In this case you descirbed (with this happening for every condition) you will need to repeat this logic for every filter condition

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```py
q_all = MyModel.objects.all()
filtered = q_all.filter(...)
if filtered.count() == 0:
    return q_all
else:
    return filtered
```

The point is that the first query (`q_all`) is not executed before you ask for `count()`. Then you know how many there are and you can return `q_all` in case. From the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/):

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

Therefore, only one query is executed effectively.

Comment: Calling `.count()` will evaluate query, so in the case where `filtered.count()` is 0 then two queries will be made. One for `filtered` queryset and one for `q_all`.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak Not within the code shown. It depends what the further processing is. For example you could filter q_all further and then evaluate. Only then, a second evaluation will be made-

Comment: This is some strange logic. I counted `q_all` query by defualt, because it's obvious that it will be evaluated at some point. I guess when someone ask on SO `how many hits to db is his query making?` you answer with 0, because you can't see the code that evaluate query at the end? /s  (Technically yes, but this is not what the person asked and we should assume that query will be used.)

Comment: I agree, it is a matter of how you look at it. I thought it is about the code that produced the query result, not what comes after.

Answer (score 0):

Your way will be very inefficient, because this part has to do set comparison, which will be expensive in the DB:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(some_value__in=values)
```

You can simply do:

```
result = <list> or MyModel.objects.all()
```

You might however wanna do some more complicated things in between. Maybe you wanna return objects with some `value__in=[1,2]`, but still return everything in case those are not found in the database either:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(some_value__in=[1, 2])
result = qs if qs.exists() else MyModel.objects.all()
```

The `qs.exists()` is much more efficient than `bool(qs)`, because that pulls all the data from the DB. `qs.exists()` only sends a single boolean and is much lighter for the DB.